# Magento product page not showing after moving servers

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.8

I moved my Magento site to a new host and everything works fine except my product page.

I get this:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'leavethe_wed.tax_calculation' doesn't exist

Any ideas why?

Comment: How did you migrate the database? The `tax_calculation` table is part of the core Magento framework - if you're missing it you've done something wrong

Comment: @RobbieAverill SQL FILE

Comment: Please be more specific. A SQL file could be anything. How did you dump the database? You've obviously missed some of the tables

Comment: @RobbieAverill i click on the import tab and imported the file

Comment: did you installed any extension related to tax, also is there any attribute exists with name `leavethe_wed.tax_calculation`

Comment: @youngkid7 since it's only a calculation table, you may just be able to get away with recreating the table. Find the setup script in Mage_Tax (probably) that creates the table (probably the `install*.php` script) and force it to run manually to recreate the table. Obviously the best option is to take another database dump and re-import it.